# How to make “Go back to initial Screen when a BottomTabNavigator's is pressed”

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

when i click an a bottom navigation tab i want the screen to go Back to the initial screen of that bottom tab for exemple when i navigate to RouteToProfile then i press  search(BottomTabNavigator) and goes back to home i still
find the screen of the RouteToprofile
ps : i'm using react navigation 3.0.0

```
  -Home
      |
       mainScreen  
       Subrouts 
      RouteToProfile 
      ....

  -Search 
        |
         mainScreen
         another page
          ....
```

```
import React from "react";

import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createAppContainer
} from "react-navigation";

import HomeScreen from "./HomeScreen";
import SettingsScreen from "./SettingsScreen";
import DetailsScreen from "./DetailsScreen";
import ProfileScreen from "./ProfileScreen";
import NotificationsScreen from "./NotificationsScreen";
import Page from "./Page";
import SearchScreen from "./SearchScreen";
import RdvConfirmation from "./RdvConfirmation";
import ProfileDoctor from "./ProfileDoctor";
import Choisirdate from "./Choisirdate";
import Choisirtime from "./Choisirtime";

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
    Page: { screen: Page }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#42f44b"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      title: "Home"
      //Header title
    }
  }
);
const SearchStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Defination of Navigaton from home screen
    search: { screen: SearchScreen },
    ProfileDoctor: { screen: ProfileDoctor },
    Choisirdate: { screen: Choisirdate },
    Choisirtime: { screen: Choisirtime },
    RdvConfirmation: { screen: RdvConfirmation }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#42f44b"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      title: "Search"
    }
  }
);

const NotificationsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Notifications: { screen: NotificationsScreen }
    //  ,MesRDv: { screen: page }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#42f44b"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      title: "Notifications"
      //Header title
    }
  }
);
const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Defination of Navigaton from setting screen
    Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
    Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
    Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#42f44b"
      },
      headerTintColor: "#FFFFFF",
      title: "Settings"
      //Header title
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: SearchScreen
  }
);
const App = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    search: { screen: SearchStack },
    Notifications: { screen: NotificationsStack },
    Settings: { screen: SettingsStack }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, horizontal, tintColor }) => {
        const { routeName } = navigation.state;
        let IconComponent = Ionicons;
        let iconName;
        if (routeName === "Home") {
          iconName = `ios-medkit${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "Settings") {
          iconName = `ios-settings${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "Notifications") {
          iconName = `ios-notifications${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        } else if (routeName === "search") {
          iconName = `ios-search${focused ? "" : "-outline"}`;
        }

        return <IconComponent name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
      }
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#42f44b",
      inactiveTintColor: "gray"
    }
  }
);
export default createAppContainer(App);
```

Comment: you can use `navigate('ScreenName')` function if you want  to navigate to specific screen. You can write this as go back action.

Comment: going back always takes us to previous screen in stack.

Comment: @avanikothari for moving into screens navigate('screeName') works fine but how can i  implement it in the  BottomTabNavigator ??  for exemple i'm navigating in  homeStacknavigator and as soon as i click on another bottomnavigateStack  the homeStacknavigator goes back to the first screen

Comment: it is the limitation of react-navigation that we cannot navigate into the screens of nested stacks. When you have created bottomTabNavigator, you have defined a scope for all four screens which is confined to the bottomTabNavigator's stack only. So you can do this I am posting as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a separate component for the HomeStack like this:

```
    const HomeStackNavigation = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
        Details: { screen: DetailsScreen },
        Page: { screen: Page }
      }
export default class HomeStack extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HomeStackNavigation
                screenProps={{ rootNavigation: this.props.navigation }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

and use this `HomeStack` as screen in bottomTabNavigator,
then use the screenProps like this in any screen of HomeStackNavigation:

```
const rootNav = this.props.screenProps.rootNavigation;
rootNav.navigate('ScreenName');
```