# how to import bottom navigator in react-navigation in other screens

Tags: react-native

I have created a bottom navigator using `react-navigation`. how can i use it to my other screens which are not included in the bottom navigator?

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator({
intro: {
    screen: IntroSlides
},
dashboard: {
    screen: createBottomTabNavigator({
        inbox: {
            screen: Inbox,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: () => (
                    <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.icon} source={require('./src/assets/MyProfileIcon.png')} />
                ),
                title: 'Profile',
            }),
        },

        favourite: {
            screen: Favourite,
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
                tabBarIcon: () => (
                    <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.icon} source={require('./src/assets/FavouriteIcon.png')} />
                ),
                title: 'Favourite',
            }),
```

Comment: Tab bar will be shown at screens which are defined in createBottomTabNavigator

Comment: I have answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56016373/how-to-make-go-back-to-initial-screen-when-a-bottomtabnavigators-is-pressed/56017131#56017131)

Answer (score 1):

Put your other items/screens in a stack navigator:

```
const Bottom = createBottomTabNavigator({
    item1: {screen: Screen1},
    item2: {screen: Screen2},
    },{
        initialRouteName: "item1",
    }
)

export default createStackNavigator({
    tabs: Bottom,
    item3: Screen3, // your other screen
})
```

and if you want hide stacknavigator from item3 screen, you can use this in your component:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    header: null
});
```